# Why is Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds:n(ps:n<1000)),fun) faster than Future(fun)?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, flutter-future

This is my code.I looked at the source code of **Future.delayed** & **Future**. **Future** & **Future.delayed** both execute **Time.run**. **Future** Duration is **Duration.zero**,But Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds:n(ps:n<1000)),fun) is faster, And what's interesting about this is that it reverses when n >= 1000 .

```
void event(){
  print("Future delayed start");
  Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds:999), (){
    print("Future delayed end");
  }).then((value) => {
    print("Future.delayed.then")
  }).whenComplete(() => {
    print("Future.delayed.whenComplete")
  });

  print("Future start");
  Future((){
    print("Future end");
  }).then((value) => {
    print("Future.then")
  }).whenComplete(() => {
    print("Future.whenComplete")
  });
}
```

This is output.

```
flutter: Future delayed start
flutter: Future start
flutter: Future delayed end
flutter: Future.delayed.then
flutter: Future.delayed.whenComplete
flutter: Future end
flutter: Future.then
flutter: Future.whenComplete
```

Thanks in advance.